# UWP Focus on AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `AutoSuggestBox` with visibility set to `Collapsed`. In the same view page, I have a button. On clicking the button, I want to show the `AutoSuggestBox`. And when the query has been submitted or the `AutoSuggestBox` has lost focus, I want to hide it again.

Here's AutoSuggestBox and the button:

```
<AutoSuggestBox Name="MainAutoSuggestBox"   
                Grid.Row="2"
                GotFocus="MainAutoSuggestBox_GotFocus"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                QueryIcon="Find"                               
                QuerySubmitted="MainAutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
                LostFocus="MainAutoSuggestBox_LostFocus"/>

<Button Name="TopBarSearchButton"
        Content="Button"
        Click="TopBarSearchButton_Click"/>
```

My code-behind:

```
class SomePage : page
{
    ...
    ...

    private void MainAutoSuggestBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //only for testing purposes
    }

    private void MainAutoSuggestBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainAutoSuggestBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        //put focus on the page
        this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }

    private void MainAutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        //Do something
        //Works fine
    }

    private void TopBarSearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleSearchButtonClick();
    }

    private void HandleSearchButtonClick()
    {
        if (MainAutoSuggestBox.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            MainAutoSuggestBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MainAutoSuggestBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }
        else
        {       
            MainAutoSuggestBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }    
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I click the button `TopBarSearchButton` 
for the first time, the visibility of `MainAutoSuggestBox` toggles but the focus is not set on the `MainAutoSuggestBox`. But from second time onwards it works as expected i.e, upon clicking the button, the visibility of `MainAutoSuggestBox` toggles as well as focus is set on the `MainAutoSuggestBox`.

During debugging, I found that when the button is clicked for the first time, 
control flow reached the line `MainAutoSuggestBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` inside `HandleSearchButtonClick()` but it never hits the

```
private void MainAutoSuggestBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

method, but from second time onwards, it does hit the

```
private void MainAutoSuggestBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

method.

Comment: The title is `UWP`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first work out why the focus wasn't set for the first time.

First, subscribe to the `Loaded` event of the `MainAutoSuggestBox`, inside the handler, you will find that the `RenderSize` of `MainAutoSuggestBox` is `<0,0>`. This makes sense, as you have set the `Visibility` of the control to `Collapsed` in XAML, resulting in the control to ignore all size changing events.

So, by the time the second line of below code hit for the first time, although the `Visibility` is set to `Visible`, the control has yet to be fully rendered, so the following `Focus()` will take no effect. After that, the control is done rendering, and that's why from the second time on the `Focus()` will now work properly.

```
    MainAutoSuggestBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    MainAutoSuggestBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

---

There's a few ways to fix this. First is to subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event and then in the handler, *only* when the old size is `<0,0>` and new size is something else, you know it's completed rendering, call the `Focus()` there.

Or more easily, don't set it to `Collapsed` in XAML but do it in the `Loaded` event handler as it will be fully rendered before collapsing -

```
MainAutoSuggestBox.Loaded += (s, e) => MainAutoSuggestBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```